# EmptyStackException из ничего в Java

Tags: java, стек

появилась такая проблема в Java, есть метод FunctionCall:

```
public void FunctionCall(Interpreter interpreter) {
    JObject callable = stack.pop();
    int argc = stack.pop().toInt();
    callable.call(interpreter,argc);
}
```

Не смотря на то что я его не вызывал мне выдает данную ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
at java.base/java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
at java.base/java.util.Stack.pop(Stack.java:84)
at learn.Frame.FunctionCall(Frame.java:127)
at learn.Frame.execute(Frame.java:112)
at learn.Interpreter.run_frame(Interpreter.java:17)
at learn.primitives.Function.call(Function.java:24)
at learn.Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

А так выглядит сам класс Frame: https://pastebin.com/pp7UA3Mj
С чем связана данная проблема?

Comment: У вас `stack` пустой, если при пустом стеке вызываете `pop`, будет выброшено исключение `EmptyStackException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема у вас здесь

```
switch ((int) code[pc]) {
    ........
    case Instruction.BRET:
        ret = new Bool(stack.pop().toBool());
    case Instruction.RET:
        System.out.println(stack.get(0));
        ret = stack.pop();
    case Instruction.CALL:
        FunctionCall(interpreter);
        pc++;
        continue;
```

Т.к. после условий `Instruction.BRET`, `Instruction.RET` нет команд выхода из `switch` то начинают выполняться последующие `case`

Comment: Cпасибо! Теперь все работает